# Spring boot 2.0.0.M1 NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>

Tags: spring-boot

I used the starter page on https://start.spring.io/ to generate a project with a number of included modules
When I try to run the tests I get a lot of log info but these lines seem key

```
10:29:33.198 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [Inlined Test Properties] PropertySource with highest search precedence
10:29:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/privilege/target/surefire/surefirebooter1615922581175854972.jar]
10:29:33.369 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at  org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:98)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:64)
```

The modules that I selected are:

- Security
- AOP
- Web Jersey (JAX-RS)
- Rest Repositories
- DevTools
- Cache
- Session
- Mobile
- REST
- Docs
- Thymeleaf
- MongoDB
- Zuul
- Zookeeper Discovery
- Solr
- Cloud
- OAuth2
- Lombok
- Retry

I had to make a few mods to the generated pom but I think that I have a reasonable set of versions.
From the "effective pom" generated by STS, get the following properties:

```
<spring-batch.version>4.0.0.M2</spring-batch.version>
<undertow.version>1.4.14.Final</undertow.version>
<httpclient.version>4.5.3</httpclient.version>
<maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.18.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
<webjars-locator.version>0.32-1</webjars-locator.version>
<spring-ldap.version>2.3.1.RELEASE</spring-ldap.version>
<spring-security-oauth.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth.version>
<hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
<groovy.version>2.4.11</groovy.version>
<rxjava2.version>2.1.0</rxjava2.version>
<byte-buddy.version>1.6.14</byte-buddy.version>
<spring-social-linkedin.version>2.0.0.M2</spring-social-linkedin.version>
<jmustache.version>1.13</jmustache.version>
<spring-cloud-connectors.version>2.0.0.M1</spring-cloud-connectors.version>
<mockito.version>2.7.22</mockito.version>
<reactor-bom.version>Bismuth-M1</reactor-bom.version>
<maven-antrun-plugin.version>1.8</maven-antrun-plugin.version>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<bitronix.version>2.1.4</bitronix.version>
<commons-beanutils.version>1.9.3</commons-beanutils.version>
<exec-maven-plugin.version>1.5.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
<atomikos.version>3.9.3</atomikos.version>
<maven-javadoc-plugin.version>2.10.4</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
<jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
<jaxen.version>1.1.6</jaxen.version>
<caffeine.version>2.5.0</caffeine.version>
<couchbase-cache-client.version>2.1.0</couchbase-cache-client.version>
<sun-mail.version>1.6.0-rc1</sun-mail.version>
<lettuce.version>5.0.0.M2</lettuce.version>
<wsdl4j.version>1.6.3</wsdl4j.version>
<jedis.version>2.9.0</jedis.version>
<javax-mail.version>1.6.0-rc1</javax-mail.version>
<lombok.version>1.16.16</lombok.version>
<maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.18.1</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
<activemq.version>5.14.5</activemq.version>
<spring-security-jwt.version>1.0.7.RELEASE</spring-security-jwt.version>
<spring-mobile.version>2.0.0.M1</spring-mobile.version>
<log4j2.version>2.8.2</log4j2.version>
<hazelcast-hibernate5.version>1.2.1</hazelcast-hibernate5.version>
<janino.version>3.0.7</janino.version>
<aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
<versions-maven-plugin.version>2.3</versions-maven-plugin.version>
<spring-kafka.version>2.0.0.M2</spring-kafka.version>
<tomcat.version>8.5.15</tomcat.version>
<postgresql.version>42.1.1</postgresql.version>
<statsd-client.version>3.1.0</statsd-client.version>
<spring-social-twitter.version>2.0.0.M2</spring-social-twitter.version>
<flyway.version>4.2.0</flyway.version>
<snakeyaml.version>1.18</snakeyaml.version>
<maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.4</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
<spring-cloud-starter-zuul.version>1.3.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-zuul.version>
<resource.delimiter>@</resource.delimiter>
<maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.10</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
<spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery.version>1.1.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery.version>
<assertj.version>3.7.0</assertj.version>
<hikaricp.version>2.6.1</hikaricp.version>
<nekohtml.version>1.9.22</nekohtml.version>
<jest.version>2.4.0</jest.version>
<javax-transaction.version>1.2</javax-transaction.version>
<hazelcast.version>3.8.1</hazelcast.version>
<glassfish-el.version>3.0.0</glassfish-el.version>
<mariadb.version>2.0.1</mariadb.version>
<javax-validation.version>1.1.0.Final</javax-validation.version>
<thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>
<spring-social.version>2.0.0.M3</spring-social.version>
<spring-security.version>5.0.0.M1</spring-security.version>
<solr.version>6.5.1</solr.version>
<maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.10</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
<neo4j-ogm.version>3.0.0-M01</neo4j-ogm.version>
<servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
<joda-time.version>2.9.9</joda-time.version>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<hibernate-validator.version>5.4.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
<jaybird.version>3.0.0</jaybird.version>
<commons-collections.version>3.2.2</commons-collections.version>
<liquibase.version>3.5.3</liquibase.version>
<maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-resources-plugin.version>
<embedded-mongo.version>2.0.0</embedded-mongo.version>
<spring-integration.version>5.0.0.M4</spring-integration.version>
<querydsl.version>4.1.4</querydsl.version>
<mongodb.version>3.4.2</mongodb.version>
<commons-codec.version>1.10</commons-codec.version>
<antlr2.version>2.7.7</antlr2.version>
<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
<xml-apis.version>1.4.01</xml-apis.version>
<selenium.version>3.4.0</selenium.version>
<jetty-el.version>8.5.9.1</jetty-el.version>
<maven-help-plugin.version>2.2</maven-help-plugin.version>
<jetty.version>9.4.5.v20170502</jetty.version>
<ehcache.version>2.10.4</ehcache.version>
<mssql-jdbc.version>6.1.0.jre8</mssql-jdbc.version>
<spring-retry.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-retry.version>
<mongo-driver-reactivestreams.version>1.3.0</mongo-driver-reactivestreams.version>
<ehcache3.version>3.3.1</ehcache3.version>
<simple-json.version>1.1.1</simple-json.version>
<couchbase-client.version>2.4.5</couchbase-client.version>
<narayana.version>5.5.24.Final</narayana.version>
<freemarker.version>2.3.26-incubating</freemarker.version>
<infinispan.version>8.2.6.Final</infinispan.version>
<unboundid-ldapsdk.version>3.2.1</unboundid-ldapsdk.version>
<httpasyncclient.version>4.1.3</httpasyncclient.version>
<thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>
<spring-social-facebook.version>3.0.0.M2</spring-social-facebook.version>
<classmate.version>1.3.3</classmate.version>
<artemis.version>1.5.4</artemis.version>
<spring-plugin.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-plugin.version>
<spring.version>5.0.0.RC1</spring.version>
<selenium-htmlunit.version>2.26</selenium-htmlunit.version>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<appengine-sdk.version>1.9.53</appengine-sdk.version>
<rxjava.version>1.3.0</rxjava.version>
<maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
<netty.version>4.1.11.Final</netty.version>
<commons-dbcp2.version>2.1.1</commons-dbcp2.version>
<htmlunit.version>2.26</htmlunit.version>
<jboss-transaction-spi.version>7.6.0.Final</jboss-transaction-spi.version>
<hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
<spring-cloud-starter-oauth2.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-oauth2.version>
<junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
<maven-install-plugin.version>2.5.2</maven-install-plugin.version>
<javax-cache.version>1.0.0</javax-cache.version>
<build-helper-maven-plugin.version>1.10</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
<javax-jms.version>2.0.1</javax-jms.version>
<jtds.version>1.3.1</jtds.version>
<mysql.version>5.1.42</mysql.version>
<slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
<git-commit-id-plugin.version>2.2.2</git-commit-id-plugin.version>
<maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
<derby.version>10.13.1.1</derby.version>
<thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
<jooq.version>3.9.2</jooq.version>
<logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
<maven-clean-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-clean-plugin.version>
<thymeleaf-spring5.version>3.0.6.M4</thymeleaf-spring5.version>
<rxjava-adapter.version>1.2.1</rxjava-adapter.version>
<spring-restdocs.version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring-restdocs.version>
<jsonassert.version>1.5.0</jsonassert.version>
<spring-session.version>2.0.0.M1</spring-session.version>
<elasticsearch.version>2.4.5</elasticsearch.version>
<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
<httpcore.version>4.4.6</httpcore.version>
<sqlite-jdbc.version>3.16.1</sqlite-jdbc.version>
<dom4j.version>1.6.1</dom4j.version>
<thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute.version>2.0.1</thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute.version>
<jdom2.version>2.0.6</jdom2.version>
<javassist.version>3.21.0-GA</javassist.version>
<jetty-jsp.version>2.2.0.v201112011158</jetty-jsp.version>
<json-path.version>2.2.0</json-path.version>
<spring-hateoas.version>0.23.0.RELEASE</spring-hateoas.version>
<spring.boot.version>2.0.0.M1</spring.boot.version>
<sendgrid.version>3.2.0</sendgrid.version>
<spring-data-releasetrain.version>Kay-M3</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
<spring-ws.version>2.4.0.RELEASE</spring-ws.version>
<dropwizard-metrics.version>3.2.2</dropwizard-metrics.version>
<commons-pool.version>1.6</commons-pool.version>
<jboss-logging.version>3.3.1.Final</jboss-logging.version>
<jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
<webjars-hal-browser.version>3325375</webjars-hal-browser.version>
<maven-war-plugin.version>2.6</maven-war-plugin.version>
<gson.version>2.8.0</gson.version>
<h2.version>1.4.195</h2.version>
<cassandra-driver.version>3.2.0</cassandra-driver.version>
<jolokia.version>1.3.6</jolokia.version>
<maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.6</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
<commons-digester.version>2.1</commons-digester.version>
<jackson.version>2.9.0.pr3</jackson.version>
<jna.version>4.4.0</jna.version>
<maven-source-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-source-plugin.version>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<commons-lang3.version>3.5</commons-lang3.version>
<maven-deploy-plugin.version>2.8.2</maven-deploy-plugin.version>
<thymeleaf.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
<commons-pool2.version>2.4.2</commons-pool2.version>
<maven-site-plugin.version>3.5.1</maven-site-plugin.version>
<maven-invoker-plugin.version>1.10</maven-invoker-plugin.version>
<spring-amqp.version>2.0.0.M4</spring-amqp.version>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<hsqldb.version>2.4.0</hsqldb.version>
```

Comment: Post your pom (you shouldn't need or should override versions as that generally will lead to errors like this).

Answer (score 10):

The constructor of `SpringApplicationBuilder` [has recently been changed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/889d43ddc4bf53178eb98aecd99df29f9f238639) in spring-boot 2.0.0.M1.

I had the same problem, but after updating to spring-cloud `Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` it disappeared. However, that's the version I see in your properties above.

In the end, I'm not exactly sure what causes your problem (and maybe shouldn't post this as an answer, but it's too long for a comment) but maybe that's a start for further investigation.

Since 2.0.0.M1 is not stable, you may want to wait for spring-boot 2.0.0 to be released. Otherwise, try deleting your local SNAPSHOT versions of spring.
I'll update this answer if I figure out more.

Comment: 2.0.2.RELEASE too.

Comment: Any version 2.X that have the fix of this issue?

Comment: i am having this problem in 2018 with SPBoot 2.0.4 + SpringCloud Finchley.RELEASE + Spring Cloud Contract 2.0.1... i was able to "solve" it when i downgraded my SpringCloud to Edgware SR4... there is any definitive solution?

Answer (score 8):

Just check **spring-cloud-starter server** version compatibility with **spring-boot-starter-parent**. This will help and it will resolve

```
15:49:31.609 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:125)
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:89)
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:364)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265)
```

In my case I've resolved this using **spring-boot-starter-parent** version 2.0.5.RELEASE and **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server** with version **Finchley.SR1**.
Also added **spring-cloud-starter-config** dependencies with it.

Thanks and Hope It will help you.

Answer (score 4):

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

adding above tag for

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

resolved my problem, it's issue with spring - cloud and spring 2.1.x versions

Answer (score 2):

Just complementing @Michel Jung's answer, I just needed to keep the spring-boot version as the same:

```
2.0.4.RELEASE
```

And add the `Finchley.RELEASE`'s mavenBom [as recommended here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/):

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.RELEASE"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the consistency between Spring boot version and Release train version. Full documentation is [HERE](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud)

You need to check **Table 1. Release train Spring Boot compatibility**

For example, if you use **Spring Boot **2.4.x**** version, consistent **Release train is 2020.0.x**

For **2.2.0.RELEASE** Spring Boot version compatible Release Train is **Hoxton.RELEASE**

In the dependencies it looks like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually these factors are very simple, just find all dependencies with prefix "spring",
find out them have difference with the train version.

[see](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12403#issuecomment-371480045)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is mainly happening because of the spring-cloud version. I am using 2.1.8.RELEASE of spring-boot-starter-parent and here are my findings

> 1. Tried by spring-cloud Camden.SR6 - Didn't work.
> 2. Tried by spring-cloud Finchley.SR1 - It worked this time.

Comment: to my understanding, you need to verify that the versions used, explicitly or through dependencies, match. have you tried making sure? you can run `mvn dependency:tree` which helps identify the versions and the dependencies that include them.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in Java 8 while doing a project with the feign dependency, but I fixed it by changing it to the following:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>`
</dependency>
```