# Unable to execute even simple spring boot admin server with spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

Pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```
@EnableAdminServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAdminApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAdminApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> When executing the spring boot server with giving the error as:Any kind of help would be appreciated...
>
> error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Why i am getting the error above? While Spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE is working and building fine with spring boot admin server 1.5.4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166221/spring-boot-2-0-0-m1-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-boot-builder-springa

Comment: I have done a lot of researches and also seen many links examples like you mentioned.Plz totally got stuck.Kindly help...

Comment: use the same version for spring-boot-parent and admin-ui. You are using 2.0.0 at one place and 1.5.4 at other

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot 2.0.0 is not yet supported by Spring Boot Admin. See: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/668

If you want to use spring boot admin you should use an older version of spring boot.

Comment: yes, I have implemented the spring boot admin server 1.5.4 with spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE. But when i change my boot version to spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE. It is showing the errors like mentioned above. I doubt there must be done some changes in pom file to work with spring boot 2 with spring boot server 1.5.4