# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a network of Spring boot microservices that I am trying to run and have difficulties with the Spring versions. I use the Spring version of `1.4.1.RELEASE` for the `artifactId` of `spring-boot-starter-parent` and have the `pom.xml` provided below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.transport.visualizer</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservices-registry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>microservices-registry</name>
    <description>Eureka Registry for Microservices</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

This runs fine for me. When I changed the version of `spring-boot-starter-parent` to the `2.2.2.RELEASE`, I received the errors,

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

I run the project from the terminal as provided,

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< com.transport.config:global-config >-----------------
[INFO] Building global-config 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ global-config >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ global-config ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ global-config ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/TransportationSimulator/GlobalConfig/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ global-config ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/TransportationSimulator/GlobalConfig/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ global-config ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/TransportationSimulator/GlobalConfig/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ global-config <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ global-config ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
13:26:54.515 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider
13:26:54.518 [background-preinit] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.18.Final
13:26:54.525 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers - Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be traversable.
13:26:54.528 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
13:26:54.529 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
13:26:54.530 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
13:26:54.530 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
13:26:54.682 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator - Loaded expression factory via original TCCL
13:26:54.686 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator as ValidatorFactory-scoped message interpolator.
13:26:54.686 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraverseAllTraversableResolver as ValidatorFactory-scoped traversable resolver.
13:26:54.686 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped parameter name provider.
13:26:54.687 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultClockProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped clock provider.
13:26:54.687 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
13:26:54.837 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/TransportationSimulator/GlobalConfig/target/classes/, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-config-server/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-config-server-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-config-client/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-config-client-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-commons/1.1.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-commons-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/1.1.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-context-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.10.1/jackson-annotations-2.10.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.10.1/jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.10.1/jackson-core-2.10.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.10.1/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.3.1/micrometer-core-1.3.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.11/HdrHistogram-2.1.11.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.10.1/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.10.1/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.10.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.29/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.29/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.29.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.29/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.1/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.18.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/5.2.1.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-rsa/1.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-rsa-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.55/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.55.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.55/bcprov-jdk15on-1.55.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/3.5.3.201412180710-r/org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.50/jsch-0.1.50.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/javaewah/JavaEWAH/0.7.9/JavaEWAH-0.7.9.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.10/httpclient-4.5.10.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.12/httpcore-4.4.12.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.13/commons-codec-1.13.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.25/snakeyaml-1.25.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.12.1/log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.12.1/log4j-api-2.12.1.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.29/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.29.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.29/slf4j-api-1.7.29.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Chaklader/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar]
13:26:54.841 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.transport.config.GlobalConfigApplication.main(GlobalConfigApplication.java:16)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.574 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-07T13:26:54+06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project global-config: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Whats the issue here and how to solve it?

Comment: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud . Spring Boot 2.2.x is compatible with springcloud release train Hoxton  . Try updating the release train version to match Spring boot version.

Comment: Note
The Camden release train was marked end-of-life.
The Camden release train builds on Spring Boot 1.4.x, but is also tested with 1.5.x.

Comment: Hopefully this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166221/spring-boot-2-0-0-m1-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-boot-builder-springa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed mine by changing the version of spring-boot-starter-parent to latest.

```html
<parent>
     <groupId> org.springframework.boot </groupId>
     <artifactId> spring-boot-starter-parent </artifactId>
     <version> 2.3.1.RELEASE </version>
</parent>
```