# Spring Starter with with Dependencies 'Spring Web' for Java 15 reports 'Failed to execute'

Tags: spring-mvc, java-15

i downloadet
from

- https://start.spring.io/

  - with Dependencies
    Spring Web and
  - choosen Java 15

run `mvn install`

and got this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project java15dependnciesWeb: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 15 -> [Help 1]`

i surprized. I thought it should be able to be installed out of the box. I using Ubuntu.

## Something similar errors:

This sound a bit like this error:

[Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624333/failed-to-execute-goal-org-springframework-bootspring-boot-maven-plugin2-2-2-r)

But this solution doesn't work for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742688/2891692

> Tag name: version Description : The version of the parent project to inherit. Version : 4.0.0

Comment: i got this erros with other  SpringBoot Jetty Starter projects. so i found out that i need stop somwhere running Jetty somwhere else. here its running somwhere else. i pressed stop here: https://i.imgur.com/4qyHDQj.png